# Can poor Internet connection affect the IO read on my server?

Tags: httpd, io, internet

I'm trying to spot the culprit causing too much IO read in my server. Issuing

```
IOTOP -ao
```

I have come accross many httpd processes among which one caught my attention:

```
PRIO   USER        DISK READ        DISK WRITE   SWAPIN   IO>        COMMAND
be/4   admin       **229.43 M**     32.00 K      0.00 %   18.03 %    httpd -k start -DSSL
```

This was triggered when I surfed to my homepage which is not IO consumptive at all. I mean, I had already examined the homepage use of IO and I never had such a figure. It is noteworthy to say that recently my Internet connection has had some fluctuations in speed which has to do with my modem, I think. Now, my question is if that has any thing to do with the heavy IO consumption in my server.

Please note that I quoted the above line as an example so my problem is not limited to this particular one, but I was curious to know the reason, anyhow.

Comment: How much is too much?

Comment: I changed the title of the question.